# Let P be a point inside triangle ABC such that ∠CPA=90 and ∠CBP =∠CAP. Prove that ∠PXY =90.

Tags: geometry

Let P be a point inside triangle ABC such that $\angle CPA=\ 90^\circ$ and $\angle CBP =\angle CAP$
Prove that ∠PXY =$\ 90^\circ$ , where X and Y are the midpoints of AB and AC respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\angle CBP=\angle CAP=\varphi$, then $\angle ACP=90^\circ-\varphi$ from $\triangle ACP$. Denote by $A'$ the foot of the altitude from $A$ in $\triangle ABC$. Since $\angle APC=\angle AA'C=90^\circ$, both $P$ and $A'$ belong to the circle over diameter $AC$. Thus $\angle AA'P= \angle ACP=90^\circ-\varphi$ as inscribed angles over $AP$ in this circle. So $\angle PA'B=\angle AA'B-\angle AA'P= 90^\circ-90^\circ+\varphi=\varphi$. In $\triangle PBA'$, $\angle PBA'=\angle PA'B=\varphi$, so $\triangle PBA'$ is isosceles triangle, and altitude from $P$ in this triangle contains the midpoint $S$ of $BA'$. Since also $PS\parallel AA'$, $PS$ is a midline of $\triangle ABA'$, so it contains the midpoint $X$ of $AB$. Therefore, $PX\perp BC$, and $BC\parallel XY$ because $XY$ is midline in $\triangle ABC$, so finally $PX\perp XY$.

Comment: +1 for the analysis. Just wondering "will B, P, Y be collinear?"

Comment: @Mick I don't think so, in general. Note that if $AC=BC$, then $P$ with the above properties is equal to $X$, so $B,P,Y$ are not collinear. Of course, in this case $P$ is not inside the triangle, but I would expect that if you take a triangle such that $AC$ and $BC$ are very close, then $P$ will be very close to $X$, and not on $BY$.